# How to get eigenvector and values with KernelPCA(scikit-learn API)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, eigenvector, eigenvalue

I've been struggling to find the way to get eigen values and eigen vectors from scikit-learn API, KernelPCA(). (PYTHON)

I figured out that I was not able to get eigen vectors or eigen values from data with scikit-learn's API thesedays.
(The data is from a gray scaled Picture)

Then, To get eigen vector and values, I created the centered Kernel matrix (K) and put it into scipy.linalg.eigh(K).
The problem is I can't find whether these eigen values and vectors are correct..
The thing is, I think, the sum of eigen values I got are not equal to 1.

If I could get eigen values and vectors with a certain API, I can compare these..

What should I do?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92171/what-do-eigenvalues-have-to-do-with-pictures

Answer (score 3):

Following [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92171/what-do-eigenvalues-have-to-do-with-pictures) and using [TruncatedSVD](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD.html) from scikits-learn documentation you can get a fast decomposition using random projections with a few lines of code:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD
im = # your image
svd = TruncatedSVD(n_components=20, random_state=42)
Utr = svd.fit_transform(im) # returns U.dot(sigma) of the svd
new_im = Utr.dot(svd.components_) # svd.components_ contains the V of the svd
```

`new_im` constains the reconstruction of the original image using the first 20 eigenvectors (generated using random projections) for the reconstruction.

Answer (score -1):

Checking if eigenvalues and eigenvectors are correct is very easy, do you really need a different API?!

```
    In [1]: from scipy.linalg import eigh

    In [2]: from numpy import matrix

    In [3]: m = matrix([[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5]])

    In [4]: eval, evec = eigh(m)

    In [5]: (m*evec - eval*evec < 0.000001).all()
    Out[5]: True
```